# Resolving URI in spark-java

Tags: spark-java

Given a relative link, such as "/v1/payments/sale/:saleId", how can "href" be resolved in this example (from the PayPal API docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/hateoas-links/)

```
{  
  "links": [{
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }, {
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/36C38912MN9658832/refund",
    "rel": "refund",
    "method": "POST"
  }, {
    "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
    "rel": "parent_payment",
    "method": "GET"
  }]
}
```

I'm building a RESTful API using Spark and need to make the API "discoverable".

Answer (score 0):

The `Request.url()` contains the URL for the current request, so using `URL(context, spec)` from `java.net` constructs the link target URL:

```
URL current = new URL(request.url()); // some resource at https://api.paypal.com/...
URL target = new URL(current "/v1/payments/sale/:saleId");
// ^^ https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/:saleId
```